# Носится, как чёрт с писаной торбой!

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть выражение: ***Носится, как чёрт с писаной торбой!***

Откуда оно взялось, интересно было бы узнать?
Что за торба писаная, с которой, собственно, и носится чёрт (либо дурак)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Писаная торба - пёстрая, цветисто расписанная сумка, холщовый мешок.Устойчивый оборот отражает   стереотипные, свойственные прежде всего простонародной культуре представления о дураке, нашедшие воплощение в пословицах и поговорках.

ДУРАК ВСЕГДА РАДУЕТСЯ

Дурак носится, потому что любит шум, суету, столпотворение, базар, праздник: Носится, как дурак. Дурак давку любит. Рад дурак празднику. Дураку каждый день праздник. Умный плачет, а дурак скачет. Дураку только пальчик покажи - засмеётся.

Дурак глупо радуется всему без разбора, всякой бессмыслице, чепухе, ерунде, особенно если это имеет яркий внешний вид, выделяется из общего ряда вещей: Рад дурак красному. Всякий дурак любит красненькое. Рад, как дурак красной шапке; Что пестро, то дураку и красно.

ТЕМА ДУРАКА И ЧЕРТА

Дурак настолько поглощен радостными впечатлениями жизни, что не замечает возможных негативных последствий своего поведения, например: Дураку хоть торба с пирогами, хоть чёрт с рогами - всё одно.  Дай дураку лошадь, он на ней и к черту уедет.

МОРАЛЬ

Фразеологизм выполняет роль эталона неверной оценки значимости, ценности людей, вещей и событий.

http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/1060/КАК_С_ПИСАНОЙ_ТОРБОЙ

Comment: Честно говоря, думал, есть какая-то сказка, связанная с чёртом или дураком у которого и могла быть писанная торба. Увы, ошибся, видимо. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Честно говоря, я знаю выражение "как дурень с писаной торбой". Вроде как дураку дали красивую игрушку, вот он с ней и носится. А Ваш вариант, возможно, какая-то "народная производная" от этого выражения.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то это контаминация - смешение двух фразеологизмов: *носится, как дурень с писаной торбой* и *боится, как черт ладана*. Так что черт здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Чаще всего я встречаю "чёрта с писанной торбой", нежели "дурня".

Comment: Зайдите в национальный корпус русского языка - одни дурни и ни одного черта. Печально, что современное поколение не знает пословиц своего народа. http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%E0%EA+%E4%F3%F0%E5%ED%FC+%F1+%EF%E8%F1%E0%ED%EE%E9+%F2%EE%F0%E1%EE%E9

Comment: А еще есть выражение "как дурень со ступой"

Comment: А почему контаминация именно с *боится, как чёрт ладана*?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с чёртом мне не встречался никогда. Это либо что-то местное, либо новый вариант. Обычно говорят о дураке или о дурне. Писаная торба, как абсолютно справедливо было замечено, - это раскрашенный мешок, сума. Вот только сума являлась атрибутом нищего: "Ходить с сумой" - нищенствовать. Могли носить торбу также, например, пастухи, но всё равно это - принадлежность очень бедного человека; тот, кто хоть чуть-чуть побогаче, мог носить, например, заплечник - прообраз современного рюкзака - или хоть корзину, короб. Вот в этом - и смысл поговорки: дурак видит яркую раскрашенную вещь и радуется ей - а на самом деле эта вещь говорит о его низком социальном и имущественном статусе. Но дурак потому и дурак, что он этого не понимает! За внешней яркостью вещи он не видит её настоящего смысла. В современном мире это можно сравнить с человеком, который носит вещи, "подделывающиеся" под фирменные, с нашитыми напоказ "лейблами", наивно считая, что никто из окружающих не заметит разницы.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, значение этой поговорки такое: человек дорожит чем-то и обращается с этой вещью или человеком очень бережно!

Answer (score -1):

Это не всегда понятно для русскоязычных людей, поскольку происходит пословица из украинской культуры. В оригинале, на украинском, эта фраза звучит так: "носиться як дурень з писаною торбою".
В русском языке говорят не "дурень", а "дурак". То же касается и фразы "писаной торбы" — по-русски так не говорят.

Comment: В русском языке есть как *дурак*, так и *дурень*. Чтобы в этом убедиться, достаточно открыть любой словарь, хоть толковый, хоть орфографический. И что «нерусского» в *писаной торбе*? Откройте словарь и посмотрите, какие значения у этого прилагательного.